# Manual Acknowledgement of Messages : Spring Cloud Stream Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

The scenario i want to implement is consume a message from Kafka , process it, if some condition fails i do not wish to acknowledge the message. For this i found in the spring cloud stream reference documentation,

autoCommitOffset
Whether to autocommit offsets when a message has been processed. If set to false, an Acknowledgment header will be available in the message headers for late acknowledgment.

Default: true.

My question is after setting autoCommitOffset to false, how can i acknowledge a message? A Code example would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what "Sprint Cloud Stream Kafka" is. However, if you use a regular Kafka client, it should provide a method called "commit()" or similar to commit offsets manually.

Answer (score 4):

I've provided an answer to the question here  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/575

Essentially it comes down to setting 

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=false`

and then handling the acknowledgment header:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
   public class ManuallyAcknowdledgingConsumer {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(ManuallyAcknowdledgingConsumer.class, args);
      }

      @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
      public void process(Message<?> message) {
         System.out.println(message.getPayload());
         Acknowledgment acknowledgment = message.getHeaders().get(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT, Acknowledgment.class);
        if (acknowledgment != null) {
           System.out.println("Acknowledgment provided");
           acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marius. Also, please share the import statements to know the API of the acknowledgement class. Wanted to see if there is a method for not acknowleding a message.

Comment: This is the answer.  Thanks Marius!

Comment: @marius-bogoevici: is this functionality available in Spring Cloud Stream Functional interfaces?