# Manual ack with Spring Cloud Stream RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to setup a scenario where the listeners will manually send ACK to RabbitMQ. I have this in my application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.acknowledge-mode=MANUAL
```

How do I send an ack from the listener?
I see from [Manual Acknowledgement of Messages : Spring Cloud Stream Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822252/manual-acknowledgement-of-messages-spring-cloud-stream-kafka) that for Kafka, we create an Acknowledgement object and call acknowledge() in it. Is there an example for RabbitMQ to do the same?

Answer (score 5):

See the [Spring Integration Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-ack). The message has two headers, `AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL` and `AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG`.

You need to call `basicAck` on the channel, passing in the delivery tag.

Answer (score 4):

```
@StreamListener(target = BAR)
public void handlerMethod(@Payload Foo foo,
                          @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
                          @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag) {
    ...
    channel.basickAck(deliveryTag, false);
}
```

The headers are added in automatic way by RabbitMQ so you can use them out of the box with your setting.