# How to manage manual ack with Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I tried several ways to manage manual ack with RabbitMQ, especially based on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048279/manual-ack-with-spring-cloud-stream-rabbitmq), but unfortunately, none of them works.

In my configuration file, I have set the acknowledge-mode to MANUAL as follow:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        magento-consumer:
          binder: rabbit
          destination: toto
          durableSubscription: false
          consumer:
            acknowledge-mode: MANUAL
```

Then, I have a `receive` method which is annotate by `@StreamListener`, which takes 4 parameters:

```java
    @StreamListener(SinkInterface.NAME)
    public void receive(
            Message<Event> m,
            @Header(name = Queue.TO_MAGENTO , required = false) Boolean header,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.CHANNEL) Channel channel,
            @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) Long deliveryTag
    ) {

        //Do something

    }
```

The issue is that the `channel` parameter is always null, so I cannot retrieve the `amqp_channel` header.

> org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'amqp_channel' for method parameter type [interface com.rabbitmq.client.Channel]

How can I retrieve this channel parameter ?
I don't understand why the `amqp_channel` is not set, and how to inject it.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that the property name needs to be corrected. The correct property name to set the acknowledgeMode is: `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channelName>.consumer. acknowledge-mode`. You can check [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#rabbit-binder-properties) for more info.